# django SelectDateWidget and bootstrap

Tags: django

I'm trying to render a SelectDateWidget with bootstrap, however when I add the class "form-control" it just appears vertically. If I don't add it it appears horizontal but unstyled.
Is there a way to break down the widget so that I can customise it as needed?

(Note I've used django widget tweaks to add the css class)

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.move_in_date.id_for_label }}">
          {{ form.move_in_date.label }}
        </label>
        {% render_field form.move_in_date.errors class="form-control" %}
        {% render_field form.move_in_date class="form-control" placeholder=form.move_in_date.label %}
      </div>
```